# Build docker image with custom config with sbt-native-packager

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am building my docker image for my scale application with sbt-native-packager.

Now I need to introduce staging and followed the recipe from the [sbt-native-packager](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/recipes/package_configuration.html#sbt-sub-modules) site. The problem is, that the the mapped `application.conf` is not picked up on boot.

I have adjusted the `build.sbt` from the recipe by the main class.

```
lazy val testPackage = project
  .in(file("build/test"))
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .settings(
    name := "app-dev",
    mainClass := Some("Main"),
    resourceDirectory in Compile := (resourceDirectory in (app, Compile)).value,
    mappings in Universal += {
      ((resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "test.conf") -> "conf/application.conf"
    }
  ).dependsOn(app)
```

I build the docker image as followed: `testPackage/docker:publishLocal`

I also played around with the `bash_template` file and added the -D parameter to pass the config file location (`-Dconfig.file=${{chdir}}/conf/application.conf`), but I did not get it running this way either.

How is it possible to add the custom `application.conf` to the class path?